# Cron jobs are not running

Tags: 16.04, bash, cron

On my Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 I am not able to run two jobs in cron. My crontab looks like this

```
root@vps:~# crontab -l
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

0  6  * * * /usr/sbin/apachectl -k graceful
0  3  * * * /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew
```

I also tried relative paths with just apachectl and letsencrypt, but nothing has changed.

When I run the commands directly, it's ok and everything works. But the jobs from cron are not executed.

What can be wrong please?

Comment: Check `/var/log/syslog` around 6:00 and 3:00 and see if these jobs have actually run.

Comment: Check journal of cron service with `sudo journalctl -u cron.service --since "03:00" --until "06:05"`

Comment: It looks like the commands are running `Aug 19 03:00:01 vps CRON[30681]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/letsencrypt renew >> /tmp/b.log 2>&1)` and `Aug 19 06:00:01 vps CRON[31804]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/apachectl -k graceful >> /tmp/a.log 2>&1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can check two things:

- Add logging:

  ```
  0  6  * * * /usr/sbin/apachectl -k graceful >> /tmp/a.log 2>&1
  0  3  * * * /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew >> /tmp/b.log 2>&1
  ```
- Check logs:

  ```
  cat /tmp/a.log && cat /tmp/b.log
  tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep -i cron
  ```

Comment: It looks like the commands are running successfully from the log files. But the behavior is strange, because yesterday I tried to renew certificates manually and one certificate needs renewal.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can consider it as resolved. The cron jobs are running, it was just a luck (or bad luck) with the certificate which needs renewal.